# Just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and can't use compiz grid window resize commands?

Tags: compiz, window-manager, 18.04

I got used to splitting my application windows on monitor into 4 sides top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right with key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key3</kbd> and so on.
It no longer works with Ubuntu 18.04. Is there any alternative for that with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: you can also just use unity & compiz in 18.04 if desired. Works fine, Install `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package. Best with lightdm rather than gdm3

Comment: On login you can technically choose "compiz/Unity" still, does that work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 dropped support for the Unity desktop compositor in favour of GNOME Shell. GNOME Shell is incompatible with Compiz. You need to look for a method to replicate this behaviour using GNOME Shell and its [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) or install and use an unofficial, community-supported version of Unity.

P.S.: There's a [follow-up question](/q/1028798/175814) with a suggestion for a replacement GNOME Shell extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the appropriate GNOME extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/

Comment: That only seems to replicate the keyboard shorts from grid, not the hotcorners

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-session-flashback, or Mate DE, and then install compiz and all is as it should be.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the instructions on how to install the Gnome Extension "Put Windows", which will give you the keyboard shortcuts you are looking for to replicate the window arrangements you want. You can snap windows to the top-right, top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left, top, bottom, left, right, or center. Repeated presses of the shrotcuts even can toggle different size arrangements of many of those.

Follow the instructions here:
[How can I snap a window in a corner with 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04/1089033#1089033)

UNFORTUNATELY, it seems this extension does *not* enable the drag-to-corner feature to make it snap to the corner. Rather, you are left only with Gnome's default drag window to the left to snap left, and drag window to the right to snap right. Dragging to the corners will NOT make them snap to the corner. You must use the keyboard shortcut for that. **IF ANYONE FINDS A WORK-AROUND TO MAKE DRAG-AND-SNAP-TO-CORNER ACTIONS POSSIBLE, PLEASE LET ME KNOW.**

Here's a screenshot of the Put Windows shortcut configuration page, copied from my answer I wrote at the link above.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try GNOME flashback or unity desktop.

To install unity type on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want GNOME flashback, type on the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.